# Есть два массива (целочисленных) размером N

Tags: c++

Есть два массива (целочисленных) размером N. Необходимо сложить наименьшее число первого с наибольшим числом числом второго и далее до наибольшего числа первого с наименьшим числом второго. То есть в результате получается массив сумм.

Comment: Необходимо - значит необходимо... Что вам мешает? Что заставило, даже не попытавшись потрудиться, обратиться к другим?

Comment: Мне кажется вам поможет простое, но, может быть не самое оптимальное решение: отсортировать 1 массив от max к min, другой наоборот, и сложить их

Answer (score 0):

Отсортируй первый массив по возрастанию, а второй по убыванию и складывай в цикле значения A[i] и B[i]